# Замена id юзера в message pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Хочу заменить значение message.from_user.id, получаемое при отправке юзером сообщения боту на любое другое в библиотеке pyTelegramBotAPI. Возможно ли это?
Пробовал `message['from_user.id'] = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем сложность я не до конца понимаю. Вам следовало бы почитать о классах.

message.from_user.id = 2